# how to pass a objectId through url in django-python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I want to pass the ObjectId of the variable in url how to do it ?

The ObjectId is obtained from the custom tag as variable 'noose'.
It is then converted to js variable and passed in url as variable 'noo'

CODE:

```
{% get_url_gs 'Exam' as noose %}
var noo = "{{noose}}"
selected_val = "{% url 'basic_temp' group_name_tag noo %} "
```

When the code is run the error obtained is 
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for `'basic_temp'` with arguments `'(u'home', '')'` and keyword arguments `'{}'` not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

`['(?P<group_id>[^/]+)/type_created/default/(?P<node>[^/]+)$']`

The url pattern used is :

`url(r'^/default/(?P<node>[^/]+)$', 'default_template', name='basic_temp')`

Comment: Are you trying to put a Django context value into a JavaScript variable and then use that JS variable in a url tag? Why?

Comment: This seems like it might be an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what @DanielRoseman is indicating in his question... "I want to pass the ObjectId of the variable in url how to do it"... can you update your question with a brief explanation of *why* you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the url pattern used. The corrected one is:
url(r'^/default/(?P[^/]+)$', 'default_template', name='basic_temp')